# Read emails from a web mail version of a client email using C#

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server, office365

I have been trying to read emails from a web mail version of a client email. Searched a lot in the internet. I was using a code I found online

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using ActiveUp.Net.Mail;
using System;

namespace GmailReadImapEmail
{
    public class MailRepository {
        private Imap4Client client;

        public MailRepository(string mailServer, int port, bool ssl, string login, string password) {
            if (ssl)
                Client.ConnectSsl(mailServer, port);
            else
                Client.Connect(mailServer, port);
            Client.Login(login, password);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Message> GetAllMails(string mailBox) {
            return GetMails(mailBox, "ALL").Cast < Message > ();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Message> GetUnreadMails(string mailBox) {
            return GetMails(mailBox, "UNSEEN").Cast < Message > ();
        }

        protected Imap4Client Client

        {
            get {
                return client ??(client = new Imap4Client());
            }
        }

        private MessageCollection GetMails(string mailBox, string searchPhrase) {
            Mailbox mails = Client.SelectMailbox(mailBox);
            MessageCollection messages = mails.SearchParse(searchPhrase);
            return messages;
        }

        public static void Main() {
            var mailRepository = new MailRepository(
                "outlook.office365.com",
                143,
                true,
                "username",
                "password"
            );

            var emailList = mailRepository.GetAllMails("inbox");

            foreach(Message email in emailList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("<p>{0}: {1}</p><p>{2}</p>", email.From, email.Subject, email.BodyHtml.Text);
                if (email.Attachments.Count > 0) {
                    foreach(MimePart attachment in email.Attachments)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("<p>Attachment: {0} {1}</p>", attachment.ContentName, attachment.ContentType.MimeType);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getiing an exception in Client.ConnectSsl(mailserver,port)
The exception is : **No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

Comment: So, you vopy/paste code, do not debugging and then dump it on us to do your job? What did you try to fix it?

Comment: @TomTom rightly said. Anyways this is not the entire copy pasted code. I had to change a bit to suit my needs. Unfortunately I have relatively no sufficient knowledge in using Activeup.Net libraries. So I am totally at sea. The first understanding I get is maybe I am getting the port number/the internet protocol I am using is wrong. Not so much for now

Comment: did you check the smtp connection details you have to use for office 365? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outlook-settings-for-POP-and-IMAP-access-for-Office-365-for-business-or-Microsoft-Exchange-accounts-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-365-URLs-and-IP-address-ranges-8548a211-3fe7-47cb-abb1-355ea5aa88a2 https://www.google.ie/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=port%20connections%20office%20365%20outlook